# How can I determine the receiver of the message in dual sim mobile

Tags: java, android, sms

Can anyone help me.I have a scene that I want to develop an app that can determine the messages in dual Sim mobile by different simcard.I don't know how to get the receiver by sms listener.Can someone help me and really appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...        
    int simSlot = intent.getIntExtra("simSlot", -1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the current solution.You help me alot.Thank you very much! :)